# Liquid template with javascript

Tags: graphql, liquid

i want to use liquid template language with graphql without going live onto shopify store , how is it possible and how many ways are there to do it and with which programming language it can be done properly

Answer (score 0):

- As long as liquid requires a Ruby server, you must program it using
  Ruby code.
- GraphQL requires a Node.js server: you must use javascript to build
  something using it.
- Access liquid's opensource repository and clone it.
- Access graphql's opensource repository and clone it.
- Follow both documentations.